# How to Convert python Tkinter desktop App to Kivy Android App

Tags: python, tkinter, kivy

I have an app that made by tkinter and I wanna convert it to a kivy app for Android.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to read the Kivy documentation, then write Kivy code to make your app do what you want, just as you presumably did with tkinter to create the application in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly convert a Tkinter app to Kivy. You would need to use the Kivy documentation to find the equivalent commands for tkinter commands, and use that to develop your Kivy application.